# Ionic 4 Slides (ion slides with swiper) centered but not the first and last

Tags: css, angular, ionic-framework, ionic4, swiper.js

I want the slider to use centered slides, but not in the first and the last ones.

When I enable the centered slides property "centeredSlides: true" and set also "slidesPerView: 1.2" I get the correct result on the middle slides, but the first and the last I want to be the left or rigth position respectively.

```
this.SlideOptionsPaths =
    {
        initialSlide: 0,
        centeredSlides: true,
        slidesPerView: 1.2,
        slidesPerGroup: 1,
        spaceBetween: 10,
        //slidesOffsetBefore: -82,
        //slidesOffsetAfter: 160,
        speed: 400,
        fadeEffect:
        {
            crossFade: true
        }
    };
```

This is the actual behavior:
[image]

And i need the first image to be aligned left...

When swiping trow the cards (the middle cards) I need this behavier (that is correctly happening):
[image]

Answer (score 1):

By the time the question was posted there was no easy way to achieve this result. But [since Swiper version 5.2](https://github.com/nolimits4web/swiper/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#swiper-520---released-on-october-26th-2019) a new `centeredSlidesBounds` parameter was added to [the API](https://swiperjs.com/api/).

All you need to do is use the following parameters in the options object:

```
{
  centeredSlides: true,
  centeredSlidesBounds: true
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on [the docs](http://idangero.us/swiper/api/) what about using:

```
{
    initialSlide: 1
}
```

which will push the slide along one so it has something to fill the gap, or

```
{
    loop: true,
}
```

which will start at the beginning but show the end wrapped around.

Because the option your asking isn't supported as far as I know.